# Проблемы после установки DataGrip (JetBrains)

Tags: mysql, sql, jetbrains, datagrip

После установки DataGrip у меня постоянно пустой экран при постоянном создании нового проекта. Не знаю как решить эту проблему. С чего начать и как мне настроить программу?

- ОС: MacOS High Sierra
- Версия программы: Jet Brains DataGrip 2017.2

Скрин с компьютера:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Отображение бокового меню в DataGrip (меню навигации)**

После создания проекта, выполните команду `cmd + e`, чтобы открылось меню и выберите `Database` *(см. картинка 1)*, чтобы открылось боковое меню *(см. картинка 2)*. После этого (для большего удобства) перенесем меню в левую часть нажав на шестеренку и выбираем `Move to -> Left` *(см. картинка 3)*.

**Настройка/добавление новых баз данных**

Для добавления базы данных нажмите на `+` в меню, которое мы настроили *(см. картинка 2)*. Выберите Data Source и базу данных с которой вы будете работать *(см. картинка 4)*. После того как выбрали нужный пункт из списка заполните данные для подключения к текущей базе данных *(см. картинка 5)*.

**УБЕДИТЕСЬ, ЧТО ВЫ СКАЧАЛИ ДРАЙВЕР!** В самом низу страницы заполнения формы подключения может гореть `Download missing driver files` (см. картинка 5). Кликом на `Download` вы установите нужные вам драйвера.

**Прежде чем нажимать "ОК" после заполнения формы** нажмите `Test connection`. Это избавит от повторного перехода в меню настроек баз данных в случае ошибки в заполнении формы подключения.

Для быстрого перехода в меню настроек баз данных - `File -> Data Sources` или комбинация клавиш `cmd + ;`.

Картинка 1:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Картинка 2:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Картинка 3:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Картинка 4:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Картинка 5:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]